# DOCX to Google Doc Conversion - merged cells become unmerged

Tags: google-docs

We are creating reports using SQL Server Reporting Services. The reports are being exported to Word(docx).  Our end users are teachers from U.S. School Districts. They access the reports by logging on to our web site and downloading them. Many of them use school provided Chrome Books and, of course, use Google Docs as their document editor and don't have easy access to MS Word. Our reports mostly contain data tables and charts. When the document gets converted to a Google Doc, any data tables that have merged cells, those cells become unmerged. Are there any tricks to keep this from happening?

[Table in Word DOCX before upload to google drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYiQW.png)

[Table after conversion in Google Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBAPm.png)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a coding question. But one thing I'd recommend is to save the exported file (docx) as pdf and then provide pdf files instead of docx. (If the end users doesn't need to modify the values, this approach would be better)

Comment: Users need to be able to modify the document, which is why it needs to be docx and not pdf.

Comment: Also, in the mean time, you might need to redirect this post to [WebApps StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) as StackOverflow is intended for coding problems and it seems the post is more in common with a WebApps issue.

Answer (score 0):

I 75% solved this. It seems that this affects reports that are exported to DOCX. If you export them to DOC it seems to solves the problem in most cases. Where I am still having trouble is with a report that is formatted in a 2-column style.